How to make .aar workable in maui project ? Already Made a Java Binding Library But Errors
I am trying integrate a android native sdk into maui, Made a project with Android Java Library Binding, By looking into the docs from microsoft. But after that total of 3 error are occuring. Which I don't known about how to fix, trying metadata but, couldn't make it out.
1. The type or namespace name 'ProgressStateEventArgs' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Ingenico.Sdk.Transaction' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  IngSdk  F:\Temps\IngSdk\obj\Release\net8.0-android\generated\src\Com.Ingenico.Sdk.Transaction.Transaction.cs
2. The type or namespace name 'IProgressStateListenerImplementor' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Ingenico.Sdk.Transaction' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   IngSdk  F:\Temps\IngSdk\obj\Release\net8.0-android\generated\src\Com.Ingenico.Sdk.Transaction.Transaction.cs
3. 'TerminalInfo' does not implement interface member 'ITerminalInfo.TerminalInfo'  IngSdk  F:\Temps\IngSdk\obj\Release\net8.0-android\generated\src\Com.Ingenico.Sdk.Terminal.TerminalInfo.cs

Thank you
I tried to add attr into metadata.xml, Don't know added in a right manner. But no luck.ingenico.aar

Could you please provide the aar file? I didn't find where to download it on the Ingenico website.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT, Here is the file link

I reproduce your problem but I check the java class in the aar. The method and member error message mentioned did exist in the java source code. And I see you post the same thread on the Q&A, you can follow up it.
